# bulk copying images in python creates empty files

Tags: python, shutil, os.system

I'm working on creating a dataset for Yolo model training. Currently the frames and annotation files are present for multiple videos in their separate folders.

Here's the code I wrote to split the images and annotation file from the different folders.

The images to be added in test/val folders are selected randomly and moved.
I've tried various copy methods (including `copy2`, `copyfileobj` from `shutils` etc) but only a few images are copied properly, the rest are empty files with size 38kb.

```
#Assume other libraries are imported

for video_folder in video_folders:
    os.chdir(os.path.join(video_folder, "obj_train_data"))
    print(f"Currently in {os.getcwd()}")
    sample_files = os.listdir("./")
    for image_file in sample_files:
        label_file = os.path.join(str(image_file[:-3] + "txt"))
        print(f"Image file name = {image_file}")
        print(f"label file name = {label_file}")
        #Generate full path.
        image_file = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), image_file)
        label_file = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), label_file)
        assert(os.path.exists(image_file))
        assert(os.path.exists(label_file))
        #rename the iamge and label file to avoid overwriting
        new_image_file_name = f"frame_{sample_moved}.PNG"
        new_label_file_name = f"frame_{sample_moved}.txt"

        # Copy the background file
        if not (os.path.exists(label_file)):
            os.system(f"cp {image_file} {os.path.join(__IMAGE_TRAIN_FOLDER__,new_image_file_name)}")
            continue

        if(sample_moved == random_indices[0]):
            try:
                random_indices.pop(0)
            except IndexError as e:
                print("array is empty!!")

            #Move file to test folder
            if(test_counter < max_test_samples_count):
                print("moving to test folder")
                os.system(f"cp {image_file} {os.path.join(__IMAGE_TEST_FOLDER__,new_image_file_name)}")
                os.system(f"cp {label_file} {os.path.join(__LABEL_TEST_FOLDER__,new_label_file_name)}")
                sleep(0.1)
                test_counter+=1
            
            #Move file to validation counter
            elif(val_counter < max_val_samples_count):
                print("moving to validation folder")
                os.system(f"cp {image_file} {os.path.join(__IMAGE_VAL_FOLDER__,new_image_file_name)}")
                os.system(f"cp {label_file} {os.path.join(__LABEL_VAL_FOLDER__,new_label_file_name)}")
                sleep(0.1)
                val_counter+=1
        else:
            print("Moving to training folder")
            os.system(f"cp {image_file} {os.path.join(__IMAGE_TRAIN_FOLDER__,new_image_file_name)}")
            os.system(f"cp {label_file} {os.path.join(__LABEL_TRAIN_FOLDER__,new_label_file_name)}")
            sleep(0.1)
        sample_moved+=1
    # Move to base directory.
    os.chdir("../../")

print(f"Total samples moved = {sample_moved}")
```

Following is the dir strucure:

```
-Images
-Labels
-video_1
  -obj_train_data
-video_2
  --obj_train_data
-video_3
  --obj_train_data
```

I utilized the following methods:

1. `os.system("cp src dest")`
2. `shutil.copy(" src dest")`

What I expect:

- All the images and respective annotation files are copied in respective folders.

What is happening:

- Only some images are copied that are proper in size and can be viewed with image viewer applications. Most of the image files are only 38 kb in size and are empty.

Comment: It looks like you're not actually filtering to make sure your image files are actually images. My guess is you're copying your label files and popping the ".png" extension on them. Try to open one of those 38 kb ".png" files with a text editor.

Comment: I'd name one of the files `;rm -rf ~;.txt`.

Comment: `shutil.copy(" src dest")` is definitely wrong; you want `shutil.copy(src, dest)`. But this is too vague to troubleshoot properly. Files which are not 0 bytes in size are by definition not empty. What's actually in those files? What do the individual file names look like? What have you done to trim down the problem to a reproducible scenario that can be debugged? See also the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

#### The mistake in code is highlighted here:

```
    print(f"Currently in {os.getcwd()}")
    sample_files = os.listdir("./")
```

This generates a list of "all" the files in the directory, which also includes `.txt` files. These files are then copied as image files later on in code.

#### How to prevent this from happening:

create a list of images only using:

```
    print(f"Currently in {os.getcwd()}")
    #create a list of all the images in the folder.
    sample_files = natsort.natsorted(img for img in os.listdir("./") if img.endswith(".PNG"))
```

This will ensure that loop only runs on images and not on `.txt` files.